# Worklight v6.0 Mobile view issue

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

When i use the Rich Page Editor with an existing project migrated from v5.0.6 workspace, i can't see any view in the "Mobile View" panel. Furthermore, i can't add any new views...

When i click on a list item of my app in the WYSIWYG Panel, i got an error:
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
com.ibm.etools.rpe.jquery.internal.mobilenavigation.JQueryMobilePanel cannot be cast to com.ibm.etools.rpe.jquery.internal.mobilenavigation.JQueryMobilePage

sometimes and randomly, others of my apps are working well.

What can block the generation of the mobile view generation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your project using JQuery at all? Or it is just Dojo?

Could you give a sample of a page where you see this error?

Comment: A defect was identified and fixed for a future Worklight release.
This happens when:
1) There's a panel widget on the page
2) There's also an <a> tag with an href to another resource (or external website, etc.), basically any link not starting with #.
The only temporary workaround at this point would be to remove either the panel or the links while you are working on the page, and put them back when you are done editing the page.

Comment: If you find the last comment useful, please mark question as answered.